# mysql search from reverse order

Tags: php, laravel, search, eloquent

I am using Laravel Framework. I have thousands of records where new records are added daily. What I want to accomplish is search keywords from database from recently inserted data to old ones.(that means, first search for last inserted id and second last inserted id and so on). This may be odd one but I need this. The main purpose of this is to make my search faster.  I need to search multiple keywords (in about 5/6 columns) that matched. According to my knowledge, Indexing all these search columns is also a option. If there is any better solution, I want to apply. Posting codes I have tried would be great, but I haven't got any to try to.

This simply would search from the beginning of table

```
$checkDuplicate = \Guest::where('uuid', $uuid)
                            ->where('first_name', 'abc')
                            ->where('middle_name', 'def')
                            ->where('last_name', 'ghi')
                            ->where('age', '50')
                            ->where('hotel_name', 'mno')
                            ->where('check_in', 'xxx')
                            ->where('check_out', 'yyy')
                            ->first();
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

If you have an auto incrementing `id` column (which you should), you can just order by it in the descending order like so: `->orderBy('id', 'desc')`. You can also set a limit of records to fetch.

[More info here in Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset).

Comment: @Alilshaq, according to document: '`The orderBy method allows you to sort the result of the query by a given column`'. I need to search but not sort the result. :)

Comment: You already have all the search columns added as `where`. Sorting those by descending ID will get the latest inserted record among your results first.

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems like you need to optimize your data structure for the queries you need to run against it. You have a hotel name column, which calls for data reduncancy. Do you have a preselected range of hotels? For instance, when searching, would it be reasonable to pick the hotel in a dropdown and query against a foreign key (`id` in a `hotels` table) instead of a varchar (which is much faster)?

**If redesigning is not an option**, you're better off by adding indices, as you stated yourself. But bear in mind that too many indices is also bad practice. I don't believe that you can force MySQL to query data with a specific strategy (ex. start with the newest).

The other problem here is that even if you do manage to get MySQL to query the newest first, it'd still want to search the rest of the dataset to conclude that there are no more results (as you do not have a limit).

Comment: Thank you, I think I got some idea from it